# Pls can anyone help, Flutter is showing this message Expected to find ']'. in main.dart file in VS code, Pls check the bottom left of the editor pls

Tags: flutter

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28),
        color: Colors.blue.shade800,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Icon(Icons.people, size: 78),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Login:")),
            ),
            
             onChanged: _controller.setLogin,

            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Senha:")),
              obscureText: true,
              onChanged: _controller.setPass,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _controller.auth();
              },
              child: const Text("Login"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `const` when you're passing values and methods from controller.
It'll give you an error.

Also your `onChanged` method is outside the `TextField`.
Here's the workig code for you:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28),
        color: Colors.blue.shade800,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Icon(Icons.people, size: 78),
             TextField(
              decoration:const InputDecoration(label: Text("Login:")),
              onChanged: _controller.setLogin,
            ),
             TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Senha:")),
              obscureText: true,
              onChanged: _controller.setPass,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _controller.auth();
              },
              child: const Text("Login"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First move your `onChanged` into the `TextField`, then in order to use `onChanged` you should remove `const`.Also you have an extra `}`. Try this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28),
        color: Colors.blue.shade800,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Icon(Icons.people, size: 78),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Login:")),
              onChanged: _controller.setLogin,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Senha:")),
              obscureText: true,
              onChanged: _controller.setPass,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _controller.auth();
              },
              child: const Text("Login"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged` should go inside `TextField` and you will also need to remove `const` from your `TextField`. Here's the full working code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28),
      color: Colors.blue.shade800,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Icon(Icons.people, size: 78),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Login:")),
            onChanged: _controller.setLogin,
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(label: Text("Senha:")),
            obscureText: true,
            onChanged: _controller.setPass,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _controller.auth();
            },
            child: const Text("Login"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```